# Difference between returning a ptr with return type * and &

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

This may sound very basic but did not find any clear answer in this forum.

In my smart pointer framework, See these functions which I'm trying to understand.

```
Example 1:
    T* getPtr() const {
    return ptr;
    }

Example 2:  
    T& operator*() {
       return *ptr;
    }
```

Example 1 is to get the address stored in ptr to be returned as pointer, to store and use it via another pointer inside the called function.

What about Example 2? return *ptr; extracts the value that ptr points to, let's say if ptr is pointing to a variable x and if the x variable has value 5, the value 5 is replaced there like return 5; but how would we return 5; as &reference?

what is returned here ? address of x?

Thanks,
Prakash

Comment: Example 1 returns a pointer to `x`. Example 2 returns a reference to `x`.

Comment: `*ptr` would not be replaced by the literal `5`. This question seems to boill down to a misunderstanding of what references are. Suppose you write `int x = 42; int& ref = x;`. Understand that first then you will also understand what happens in your case

Comment: @CristiFati, Nope, sorry, My question is how can we assign a value to a reference?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I understand the direct way of using the reference and it's like a creating an alias. But here we have a pointer pointing to x and de referencing a pointer which would get the value stored in x right? what if i print *ptr there? will i get address or value? it'a value right.

Comment: then whats wrong with the return value of the function being an alias ?

Comment: When you dereference a pointer, you get what it points to, not to a value. The location the pointer is pointing to might contain a value, which you can copy, but you don't get the value itself by the operation.

Comment: I suggest you get a pen and a paper. On the paper draw two boxes. Label one box `ptr` and the other `x`. Now draw an arrow from `ptr` pointing to `x`. That's really how pointers work. When you dereference `ptr` you follow the arrow to get to `x`. `*ptr` is `x`, not the value of `x`.

Comment: I can understand what you say, i got confused because if i print *ptr it prints the value and not the address of x.

Comment: @PrakashGiBBs Yup, `*` has different meaning in different contexts. In a variable declaration, it means you're declaring a pointer while in an expression such as `*ptr` it means you're dereferencing a pointer `ptr`.

Comment: `*ptr` *is* `x`. If you print `*ptr` or `x` you get the same result. Think of `*ptr` as an alias of `x`. So when you print `*ptr` you follow the pointer to `x`, get the value from `x` and print it. If you want to print the address or location of `x`, print the actual value of `ptr` itself (not that there's no dereference then).